# Mounting DL160 and DL380 G6 -- rack requirements?

Tags: hp, rackmount

I'm building a home lab and I'm wondering what equipment is necessary to rackmount a couple HP ProLiant servers.  I have a DL160 G6 and a DL380 G6 sitting on a table right now.  What will I need to properly mount these servers in a rack?  Also, am I looking at needing a 800mm rack?  These things are huge; they have a depth of about 30" if I count in the cables attached.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a standard 4-post rack with square holes and the appropriate rail kits for each server.

I wouldn't bother rack mounting these systems for your home. The cost of the rails is probably as much as the servers are worth today :)